# How to sort tags by date with nodegit?

Tags: javascript, nodegit

How can we get the tags from a git repository and sort them by their related commit date ?

The Tag.list only returns names and Tag.lookup needs an OID so how to we fill in the missing part of converting the tag name to a Tag or tag id ?

Answer (score 1):

After reading the... luagit2 docs (!) to actually understand how libgit works, here is a solution:

```
nodegit.Repository.open(repoPath).then(repo =>
  nodegit.Tag.list(repo)
  .then(list =>
    Promise.all(
      list.map(tagName =>
        nodegit.Reference.lookup(repo, `refs/tags/${tagName}`)
        .then(ref => nodegit.Commit.lookup(repo, ref.target()))
        .then(commit => ({
          tag: tagName,
          date: commit.date().toJSON(),
        }))
      )
    )
  )
  .then(tags => tags.sort((a, b) => (a.date < b.date ? -1 : 1)))
```